# How to access Public Ip

Tags: ip

I am unable to access my linux server's public ip address The only ip address i can access is Private ip address.

I asked my hosting provider to help me regarding this issue but they just said
"You simply need to generate a private key for your server and then you will be able to use the public ip. Unefortunately we don't provide assistance about it."

I just want to know how can i generate private key to access my public ip address.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to SSH into your server using the public IP address?

Generating a public key on your computer (or server) that you want to access the server from is fairly easy (if this is not done already)

To generate a public ssh-key on your COMPUTER:

```
ssh-keygen

Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
13:13:13:13:13:13:13:37:37:37:37:37:37:37:37:37 root@HOSTNAME
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|         .+o+o.+o|
|         o+.+.+.=|
|         +.* o oo|
|         .= o E .|
|        S .o     |
|         ..      |
|        R00R     |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

In your catalogue ~/.ssh you will then find the file id_rsa.pub.

Copy the text in id_rsa.pub and place it in a file called authorized_host in the ~/.ssh on your server.

You can read more about the procedure here:

https://www.debian.org/devel/passwordlessssh

Comment: No, he's just trying to reword his question to hide the fact that he's having an issue setting up cpanel.  Cpanel and his ISP have already blown him off.  So he provided even less info.  The opposite fix to why most of us hate and close questions about panels.

Comment: Well, I tried my best.

Comment: Can't ask for anything more.  :/

Comment: OP should start reading the docs, provided by the hosting provider.